# iOS scrollView inside UITableCellView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a strange issue with `UIScrollView` in storyboard. I created custom `UITableViewCell` and I want to have `UIScrollView` inside it. When I do it in code it works like a charm. I do it like that:

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    if (self)
    {
        UIScrollView *scroller = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 25, 650, 25)];
        scroller.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;

        UILabel *contentLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320*4, 25)];
        contentLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        contentLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            [str appendFormat:@"%i ", i];
        }
        contentLabel.text = str;

        [scroller addSubview:contentLabel];
        scroller.contentSize = contentLabel.frame.size;
        [self addSubview:scroller];

    }

    return self;
}
```

but when I create UIScrolView in storyboard and put in in my prototype cell, connect outlet with customCell class and then to exactly the same like that:

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    if (self)
    {
        storyboardScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;

        UILabel *contentLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320*4, 25)];
        contentLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        contentLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            [str appendFormat:@"%i ", i];
        }
        contentLabel.text = str;

        [storyboardScrollView addSubview:contentLabel];
        storyboardScrollView.contentSize = contentLabel.frame.size;
}

    return self;
}
```

my cell is empty. Do you know what is wrong with it?

Comment: I don't think you can create outlets in prototype cells.

Comment: I can, I do it before. I create custom class inherit UITableViewCell and set custom class property in storyboard and its work. I just have problem with this particular problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder`function, IBOutlets are not connected with your class yet. So the pointers will have `nil` They will be connected when `- (void)awakeFromNib` function is called.

So you can do like this.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    storyboardScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;

    UILabel *contentLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320*4, 25)];
    contentLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    contentLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        [str appendFormat:@"%i ", i];
    }
    contentLabel.text = str;

    [storyboardScrollView addSubview:contentLabel];
    storyboardScrollView.contentSize = contentLabel.frame.size;
}
```

Comment: Yeah thats works, but now, when I try to add some controls in storyboard into storyboardScrollView it stops scrolling. Do you know what is wrong?

Comment: @AYMADA Please upvote and mark the answer as correct if it has helped you. Thanks.

Comment: Please set the contentSize of the scrollView. Only when scrollView's contentSize is greater than its frame size, it will have a facility to scroll.
Do something like this. `[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height + 100)];'

Set the values in `CGSizeMake` to appropriate values.

Comment: thats strange but when I add label progrmatically it scrolling but when I add additional control in storyboard it stops scrolling. Have you any idea why?